# Function for disabling or deleting users

Tags: powershell

Hi I am working on a function that either deletes or disables a user in AD, by specifying either the Remove or disable parameter.
If the parameters are set to true, the action should be performed.
When I run my script it find the User and outputs it, when it comes to the disable block it prompts me for user Identity and disables the user when specifying it in the Command window.

I am new to PowerShell functions, can anyone tell me where am going wrong?

```
function Remove-User{
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$User,
[bool]$Remove,
[bool]$Disable
)

if (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $User})
{    Write-Output $User
     if($Disable = $true){
        
         Set-ADUser -SamAccountName $User -Enabled $false
    }
    elseif($Remove = $true){
     Remove-ADUser -Identity $User
    }
    else{
        Write-Output "Done"
    }
}

else{
    Write-Output "User doesn't exist"
}
}
       
   Remove-User -User "TT" -Disable $true
```

Comment: In PowerShell you test for equality with `-eq`. `=` is the assignment operator, which unfortunately also returns a value, thereby allowing maximum confusion when `if ($Disable = $true)` is always `$true`.

Comment: And if you want to check if `$Disable` is true you can do it like this: `if($Disable) ...`

Comment: What happens when a user of this function provides both parameters?  ... ;-)

Comment: BTW: When none of the parameters is provided your function `Remove-User` will neither remove the user nor disable it but will claim *"Done"*.  ;-)

Comment: If it is for learning purposes it's fine. But you may reconsider the logic of your function. With the verb *Remove* it'd be surpising if the user is just disabled. If you still want to use a single cmdlet I'd recommend to use a switch parameter where you alter the default behaviour. And BTW: There is already a cmdlet for disabling users ... `Disable-ADAccount`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking to have a function that can perform one of both actions but not both at the same time, if that's the case, it might be a good idea to have just one parameter (`-Action`) that uses a [`ValidateSet` attribute declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validateset-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2). In addition, since both actions you want to perform can have high impact in Active Directory, it might be a good idea to use [`ConfirmImpact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2#confirmimpact) set to **High** so the function always prompts for confirmation unless `-Confirm:$false`.

```
function Remove-User {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
        [string] $Identity,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('Disable', 'Remove')]
        [string] $Action
    )

    process {
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess([string] $Identity, $Action)) {
            try {
                if($Action -eq 'Disable') {
                    return $Identity | Disable-ADAccount
                }
                $Identity | Remove-ADUser
            }
            catch {
                $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when calling the function only one "Action" will be available:

[image: demo]

And the function will prompt for confirmation by default unless `-Confirm:$false` is used:

```
PS /> Remove-User john.doe -Action Remove

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Remove" on target "john.doe".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Also, [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#-whatif) becomes a possibility when the function [`SupportsShouldProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2):

```
PS /> 'john.doe', 'jane.doe' | Remove-User -Action Disable -WhatIf

What if: Performing the operation "Disable" on target "john.doe".
What if: Performing the operation "Disable" on target "jane.doe".
```